# First law of thermodynamics for a rotating ball of hot gas

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I want to write down the energy conservation of a rotating ball of hot gas, as given by first law of thermodynamics:

$$ \mathrm{d}Q=\mathrm{d}U+\mathrm{d}W$$

I know that I can write:

$$\mathrm{d}Q=nC\mathrm{d}T$$

$$\mathrm{d}U=nC_v\mathrm{d}T$$

The problem I am facing is writing the expression $\mathrm{d}W$. How do I go on with writing this term?

The system is an isolated system. The ball is a hollow sphere filled with an ideal gas.

Comment: What is the system? The "hot gas"? What are its boundaries? The ball? What kind of "ball"?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the "system" is a hot ideal gas and its boundary is a hollow sphere.

You said the system is "isolated". By definition an isolated system cannot exchange mass or energy with its surroundings. That would mean your hollow sphere is both rigid, meaning there can be no boundary work (expansion or compression) and thermally insulated, meaning no heat transfer can occur between the gas and surroundings.

So for your isolated system, $dW=0$ and $dQ=0$, and therefore $dU=0$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A star isn't an isolated system. It is constantly radiating heat into space.

Comment: In your answer we get dQ=dU=dW=0 if the system is in equilibrium. What happens if the system is not in equilibrium.

Comment: Its entropy can increase

Comment: If entropy increases then how do I write dW I am back to square one

Comment: Entropy is property associated with the second law. I already told you dW has to be zero for an isolated system per the first law. The two laws are independent of one another